# How do I express this 1-to-1 in EF 7 fluent modelling?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to migrate an EF 6 model to EF 7, but I am stuck on one point. I have tried suggestions from several people to no avail.

This is the property as expressed in EF 6:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.StockItemHolding)
    .WithRequired(e => e.StockItem);
```

With the code like this, I get the following error:

> Error CS1061  'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a
>   definition for 'HasOptional' and no extension method 'HasOptional'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'EntityTypeBuilder'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have checked the documentation and `WithRequired` is the problem. It has been sort of replaced by `WithOne`. Many-to-many relationships work nicely, like this one:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>()
    .HasMany(e => e.StockItemTransactions)
    .WithOne(e => e.StockItem).IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: What exactly is the Problem being faced ?

Comment: What about `HasOne`?

Comment: Thank you, @GertArnold. It's very complex, so I'm not sure it will work, but it compiles and you win. Answer and I will accept.

Comment: HasOne is the replacement for HasOptional() , is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF Core Fluent API `Required` / `Optional` (as well as `Dependent` / `Principal`) is no more part of the `Has` / `With` methods. They has been replaced with `HasOne` / `WithOne` in combination with `IsRequired`.

However, there are some other important details regarding `one-to-one` relationships in EF Core.

First, `IsRequired` applies only to **dependent** entity, i.e. from the principal side the relationship is always optional.

Second, you need to specify the dependent foreign key, which could be the PK or separate field (either explicit or shadow).

So the equivalent EF Core configuration for the aforementioned EF6 configuration (which creates [Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)) will be like this (assuming `StockItemHolding` PK is called `Id`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>()
    .HasOne(e => e.StockItemHolding)
    .WithOne(e => e.StockItem)
    .HasForeignKey<StockItemHolding>(e => e.Id);
```

Comment: Or `.HasPrincipalKey<StockItem>(i => i.ID);` where `ID` is `StockItem`'s PK. I only just started to look into EF core, now it seems stable enough to make it worth the time & effort. Well explained, by the way! Maybe worth noting that, to my surprise, `StockItem.StockItemHolding` can't be made required (in validation) with data annotations as it could in EF6. (Although here, that doesn't matter).

Comment: @GertArnold Hi Gert. Regarding looking at EF Core, same here:) Still not stable enough IMHO (mainly the left outer joins issues). The idea of splitting the execution between SQL and in memory is interesting (basically should avoid unsupported exceptions), but a bit scary for the people like me that don't want surprises like reading the whole table in memory. Luckily it's configurable. What about required dependent, it cannot be enforced in db anyway.

Comment: Sure, I wish the client evaluation error (instead of warning) would have been the default. That's right, a required dependent can't be enforced by the database (basically because simultaneous inserts don't exist) but client-side validation could help in some cases.